# Scala Objects and the rise of singletons

Tags: scala, functional-programming

General style question.

As I become better at writing functional code, more of my methods are becoming pure functions. I find that lots of my "classes" (in the loose sense of a container of code) are becoming state free. Therefore I make them objects instead of classes as there is no need to instantiate them.

Now in the Java world, having a class full of "static" methods would seem rather odd, and is generally only used for "helper" classes, like you see with Guava and Commons-* and so on.

So my question is, in the Scala world, is having lots of logic inside "objects" and not "classes" quite normal, or is there another preferred idiom.

Comment: Wait, if they are state free, why are they even objects and not simply functions?

Comment: Don't you need to put the functions inside something, which is  my question. I have a bunch of related functions, they're inside an Object, simply to act as a container. Is that considered best practice in Scala or not.

Comment: In the functional world we call these container modules. Miranda did so, F# carries on with that. "General style question" is probably the reason the Scala creators wanted their container to be an object.

Comment: Ah, modules are first-class values: http://2013.flatmap.no/spiewak.html

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As you mention in your title, objects are singleton classes, not classes with static methods as you mention in the text of your question.

And there are a few things that make scala objects better than both static AND singletons in java-world, so it is quite "normal" to use them in scala.

For one thing, unlike static methods, object methods are polymorphic, so you can easily inject objects as dependencies:

```
scala> trait Quack {def quack="quack"}
defined trait Quack

scala> class Duck extends Quack
defined class Duck

scala> object Quacker extends Quack {override def quack="QUAACK"}
defined module Quacker

// MakeItQuack expects something implementing Quack
scala> def MakeItQuack(q: Quack) = q.quack
MakeItQuack: (q: Quack)java.lang.String

// ...it can be a class
scala> MakeItQuack(new Duck)
res0: java.lang.String = quack

// ...or it can be an object
scala> MakeItQuack(Quacker)
res1: java.lang.String = QUAACK
```

This makes them usable without tight coupling and without promoting global state (which are two of the issues generally attributed to both static methods and singletons).

Then there's the fact that they do away with all the boilerplate that makes singletons so ugly and unidiomatic-looking in java. This is an often overlooked point, in my opinion, and part of what makes singletons so frowned upon in java even when they are stateless and not used as global state.

Also, the boilerplate you have to repeat in all java singletons gives the class two responsibilities: ensuring there's only one instance of itself and doing whatever it's supposed to do. The fact that scala has a declarative way of specifying that something is a singleton relieves the class and the programmer from breaking the single responsibility principle. In scala you know an object is a singleton and you can just reason about what it does.

Comment: I think it cannot be stressed enough that a scala object can extend anything, which is the basis for using it with the dependency injection idiom. Thanks for giving an example!

Comment: @ChristianSchlichtherle Thanks, I just wish I had a better example. I don't like much the contrived one I gave...

Answer (score 4):

You can also use package objects e.g. take a look at the scala.math package object here
https://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/browser/scala/tags/R_2_9_1_final/src//library/scala/math/package.scala

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I would say it is normal.

For most of my classes I create a companion object to handle some initialization/validation logic there. For example instead of throwing an exception if validation of parameters fails in a constructor it is possible to return an `Option` or an `Either` in the companion objects apply-method:

```
class X(val x: Int) {
  require(x >= 0)
}
// ==>
object X {
  def apply(x: Int): Option[X] =
    if (x < 0) None else Some(new X(x))
}
class X private (val x: Int)
```

In the companion object one can add a lot of additional logic, such as a cache for immutable objects.

objects are also good for sending signals between instances if there is no need to also send messages:

```
object X {
  def doSomething(s: String) = ???
}
case class C(s: String)

class A extends Actor {
  var calculateLater: String = ""
  def receive = {
    case X => X.doSomething(s)
    case C(s) => calculateLater = s
  }
}
```

Another use case for objects is to reduce the scope of elements:

```
// traits with lots of members
trait A
trait B
trait C

trait Trait {

  def validate(s: String) = {
    import validator._
    // use logic of validator
  }

  private object validator extends A with B with C {
    // all members of A, B and C are visible here
  }
}

class Class extends Trait {
  // no unnecessary members and name conflicts here
}
```